# background: url() inside requestAnimationFrame()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few sprites like:

`sprint1.jpg
sprint2.jpg
...
sprintX.jpg`

I want to animate through the elements background css property and set the next image however it doesn't work in Chrome and in FireFox I sometimes see the animation. The code is like this:

`function render() {
  $('#element').css('background', 'url("'+next_image_path+'")');
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();`

**Note!** I am preloading all the assets and not running the code until all are loaded.

**Another Note!** I could try to do the same with image sprites but I am not sure if there's any luck there while animating.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't want to load assets there and the code is as simple as shown. I think there may be some optimization in Chrome or it simply does set the background too slowly so on next frame it's not rendered yet